# Install ScicosLab Scientific Linux

Tags: package-management, dependencies, scientific-linux

I am trying to install [ScicosLab](http://www.scicoslab.org/) on Scientific Linux 7 and have run into package dependency issues. I am moderately skilled with Ubuntu but have no experience with Scientific Linux or anything like it. I download the .rpm file from ScicosLab's site and run `yum localinstall scicoslab-gtk-4.4.1-1.sl6.x86_64.rpm` as root. It gives me an error:

```
Error: Package: scicoslab-gtk-4.4.1-1.x86_64 (/scicoslab-gtk-4.4.1-1.sl6.x86_64)
           Requires: libwebkit-1.0.so.2()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have tried to install this package but cannot seem to get it...

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I did. I did a minimal install of Scientific Linux 7.5 in Virtualbox. I tried installing this package and got the same error. 
After some searching around this is how I managed to fix it.

I installed the epel repository.

```
yum install epel-release
```

I added the Scientific Linux 6.10 repo as the specific webkitgtk, libicu and libxcb versions required by this package were found there.

```
[root@scinlinux ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/sci610.repo
[sci_6.10]
name=Scientific Linux 6.10 repo
baseurl=http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.10/x86_64/os/
gpgcheck=0
[root@scinlinux ~]#
```

After that the package got installed without any problems. In the below output I've displayed the packages that were fetched from the epel and sci-6.10 repos.

```
[root@scinlinux ~]# yum install /tmp/scicoslab-gtk-4.4.1-1.sl6.x86_64.rpm
Examining /tmp/scicoslab-gtk-4.4.1-1.sl6.x86_64.rpm: scicoslab-gtk-4.4.1-1.x86_64
Marking /tmp/scicoslab-gtk-4.4.1-1.sl6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package scicoslab-gtk.x86_64 0:4.4.1-1 will be installed
.
<snipped>
 libicu                                 x86_64         4.2.1-14.el6                   sci_6.10                                  4.9 M
 libxcb                                 x86_64         1.12-4.el6                     sci_6.10                                  179 k
 vte                                    x86_64         0.28.2-10.el7                  epel                                      361 k
 webkitgtk                              x86_64         1.4.3-9.el6_6                  sci_6.10                                  6.3 M
```

Note that in the below output the repos other than epel and sci_6.10 were already installed when Sci_linux 7.5 was installed.

```
[root@scinlinux ~]# yum repolist
repo id                                          repo name                                                                      status
*epel/x86_64                                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                 12,756
repos/x86_64                                     Scientific Linux repos - x86_64                                                    20
sci_6.10                                         Scientific Linux 6.10 repo                                                      6,860
sl/x86_64                                        Scientific Linux 7x - x86_64                                                    9,957
sl-extras/x86_64                                 Scientific Linux Extras - x86_64                                                1,066
sl-fastbugs/x86_64                               Scientific Linux 7x - x86_64 - bugfix updates                                   1,013
sl-security/x86_64                               Scientific Linux 7x - x86_64 - security updates                                   637
repolist: 32,309
[root@scinlinux ~]#
```

Comment: What would be the best way to add that SL 6.10 repository? I have tried to run `yum-config-manager --add-repo http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.10/x86_64/os/` but your second step shows nothing there.

Comment: You can just create the below file.
 
`[root@scinlinux ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/sci610.repo
[sci_6.10]
name=Scientific Linux 6.10 repo
baseurl=http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.10/x86_64/os/
gpgcheck=0
[root@scinlinux ~]#`